# can we show the orig.ident in separate windows by using Seurat

Tags: single-cell

I'm curious about can we show the orig.ident in sprat windows by using Seurat? Here are my code and the fig I got. Is it possible that I can separate each orig.ident into a single panel? `DimPlot(whole,group.by = "orig.ident", reduction = "umap")`[image]

Comment: Answered on GitHub here: https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/2106

Answer (score 1):

The `DimPlot()` function of the new version of Seurat, `Seurat v3` has a `split.by` argument, which splits the plot based on the levels of the variable provided. You basically need to provide a column from the `@metadata` slot:

```
DimPlot(whole, split.by = "orig.ident", reduction = "umap")
```

If you are using `Seurat v2`, you can have the `DimPlot()` function return the `ggplot` object created and then use `facet_wratp()` or `facet_grid()` to generate facets based on your variable of interest.

Comment: Hi haci, I'm using Seurat v3. And I do not precisely know what you mean. Can you send me the code to have tried? Thank you.